# What is Google Map’s knowledge of historic street names?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, address

I am geocoding historic addresses in Ireland using Google Maps (free access) but in some cases Google Maps returns an address with a different street name. For example, when I enter the address of the Forthriver Primary School that was recorded on Ballygomartin Road, Northern Belfast in 1990 it is geocoded to a school ('point_of_interest', 'school') on Cairnmartin Road.

Is Google Maps utilizing knowledge of historic street names but providing the updated street name? How do I know it is locating the correct address, especially in cases where there is no point of interest to identify (just an old street name)?

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think you will get an accurate answer. You would need to know someone inside Google. But I would guess they keep histories of street name from when they were capturing data, so name changes after 2005 would be incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is Google Maps utilizing knowledge of historic street names but
>   providing the updated street name?

As you guessed, Google does update their Geocoding data time by time from various sources. One of them I know, would be [their partners](https://cloud.withgoogle.com/partners/). On top of updating addresses, they would also, for example, update street view.

> How do I know it is locating the correct address, especially in cases
>   where there is no point of interest to identify (just an old street
>   name)?

You can perform the lookup of "old street name -> location on a map" on other Geocoding service, and compare the results side by side. Same approach should works on reverse Geocoding too.